# How can I add the reactive y axis labels in shiny with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

---

```
enter code here
```

I am working to create a reactive dashboard with shiny where the y axis would be according to input from user through "y = input$column1". I was able to plot the barchart but **I would like to see the value on top of each bar**.
Sample data
| quarter|  P_activity  |    A_CP| B_CP
1        101            1600    2000
2        102            1230    2400
3        103            1500    2600

Server script

```
function(input, output){
  
  pData1 <- reactive({
    
    filteredData <- subset(allData, P_Activity == input$P)
    
    
    final <- data.table(filteredData)[,list(A_CP = sum(A_CP)),
                                      
                                      
                                      by = list(quarter)]
    
    return(final)
    
    
    
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    plot <- ggplot(data = pData1(), aes_string(x= "quarter", y = input$column1))
    plot <- plot + geom_col(fill = "blue")
    plot
     
  })

  }
```

ui script

```
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "SSSS"),
                  

 dashboardSidebar(
   sidebarMenu(
     menuItem(text ="Summary",tabName = "plots"),
     
     selectInput(inputId = "P", label = "Select a P:", choices = unique(allData$P_Activity), selected = "101"),
    
     selectInput(inputId = "column1", label = "Outcome", choices = c("A_CP"))
   )
 ),
 dashboardBody(
   
   tabItems(
     tabItem(tabName = "plots",
             plotOutput("plot1",width =350, height =200)  
             )
   )
 )
)
```

The Data frame has 3 attributes:Quarter,A_CP, B_CP, where the A_CP is plotting as input$column1 against quarter.

I have serched a lot but since the y is a reactive variable , it looks bit rare to find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please make sure you share data & code in a reproducible format (state any non base-R libraries). In this case, we should be able to copy & paste code you provide to run the sample app. Currently, you have multiple typos ("PDAta1" vs. "PData1") and errors in your code, and sample data as an image (which we cannot copy & paste). In this form, we're spending time fixing your example code.

Comment: I am also a bit unclear on what you're actually trying to achieve? Your sample app has only one choice for `"column1"`, so the y axis value would always be "A_CP". I thought this should change based on user input? If so, I recommend changing your minimal app to reflect this use case.

Comment: Hi @Maurits, thanks. My goal is to see the value of Y axis on top of the bar

Comment: Code is still not reproducible. I assume you are using `shinydashboard`, `shiny` and `data.table` (always *explicitly* list any non base-R packages)? Please edit your post to include a sample app that we can re-run when copy & pasting into an empty R document.

Comment: Try `plot <- plot + geom_text(aes_string(label = input$column1), vjust = -.1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are after something like this (I have cleaned up your code).

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)

# Sample data
allData <- data.frame(
    quarter = 1:3,
    P_Activity = as.character(c(101, 102, 103)),
    A_CP = c(1600, 1230, 1500),
    B_CP = c(2000, 2400, 2600))

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
    
    dashboardHeader(title = "SSSS"),
    
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem(text ="Summary", tabName = "plots"),
            selectInput(
                inputId = "P", 
                label = "Select a P:", 
                choices = unique(allData$P_Activity), 
                selected = "101"),
            selectInput(
                inputId = "column1", 
                label = "Outcome", 
                choices = c("A_CP")))
    ),
    
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(
                tabName = "plots",
                plotOutput("plot1", width =350, height = 200)))
    )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output){

    pData1 <- reactive({
        
        filteredData <- subset(allData, P_Activity == input$P)
        data.table(filteredData)[ , list(A_CP = sum(A_CP)), by = list(quarter)]
        
    })
    
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        
        ggplot(
            data = pData1(), 
            aes_string(x = "quarter", y = input$column1, label = input$column1)) +
            geom_col(fill = "blue") +
            geom_text(vjust = -0.5) +
            scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.2)))

    })
    
}

# Run
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]